# VS2015 inside ESXi VM / no SLAT available?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator, esxi

I've set up a Windows 10 VM on my ESXi 6 machine and installed VS2015 in order to develop Windows Phone / Android apps. As the device emulator is build around   HyperV, I've added the following lines to my VMX files:

```
monitor.virtual_exec = "hardware" 
vhv.enable = "TRUE" 
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
```

The Guest OS is set to either "Windows 10 64-bit" or "Windows Server Threshold (64-bit)". But if I'm trying to run a debug session, VS complains about missing SLAT support. My host CPU definitely supports SLAT (Xeon E5-v3) and it is enabled in the BIOS. If I query the vSphere host capabilities, it clearly states that "NestedHV" is available.

I can even launch the HV Management application and start the debugging target manually... but it seems that VS2015 won't connect to it and still complains about missing SLAT support.

Is there anything I can try?

Comment: Same issue here. I can start and navigate through the phone OS if i start and connect from Hyper-V Manager. But i cannot start a debug session from VS 2015, as it complains that i'm missing Second Address Translation.

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue.
Found out, that enabling of Hyper-V disables SLAT.